# Generic way to find or create an object in LINQ to SQL?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Quite often in my [LINQ to SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query#LINQ_to_SQL_.28formerly_called_DLINQ.29) code, I need to "find or create" an entity as such:

```
var invoiceDb = ctx.Invoices.FirstOrDefault(a => a.InvoicerId == InvoicerId &&
                                                 a.Number == invoiceNumber);
if (invoiceDb == null)
{
    invoiceDb = new Invoice();
    invoiceDb.Number = invoiceNumber;
    ctx.Invoices.InsertOnSubmit(invoiceDb);
}
```

I'm looking to make this a generic method... Any good ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with these extension methods that seems to work well for me.

```
    public static T FindOrCreate<T>(this Table<T> table, Func<T, bool> find, Action<T> create) where T : class, new()
    {
        T val = table.FirstOrDefault(find);
        if (val == null)
        {
            val = new T();
            create(val);
            table.InsertOnSubmit(val);
        }
        return val;
    }

    public static T FindOrCreate<T>(this Table<T> table, Func<T, bool> find) where T : class, new()
    {
        return FindOrCreate(table, find, a => { });
    }
```

And it's used like so:

```
    var invoiceDb = ctx.Invoices.FindOrCreate(a => a.InvoicerId == InvoicerId &&
                                                     a.Number == invoiceNumber);
    invoiceDb.Number = invoiceNumber;
```

Or

```
    var invoiceDb = ctx.Invoices.FindOrCreate(a => a.InvoicerId == InvoicerId &&
                                                     a.Number == invoiceNumber,
                                              a => a.Number = invoiceNumber);
```

Comment: That will always set the "Number" property on the entity, marking it as dirty. This can/will give you unnecessary updates when performing SubmitChanges()

Answer (score 2):

VB.NET version:

```
Module dbi
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
    Public Function FindOrCreate( _
        Of T As {Class, New})(ByVal table As Data.Linq.Table(Of T), _
        ByVal find As Func(Of T, Boolean), _
        ByVal create As Action(Of T)) _
        As T

        Dim val As T = table.FirstOrDefault(find)
        If val Is Nothing Then
            val = New T()
            create(val)
            table.InsertOnSubmit(val)
        End If
        Return val
    End Function

    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
    Public Function FindOrCreate( _
        Of T As {Class, New})(ByVal table As Data.Linq.Table(Of T), _
        ByVal find As Func(Of T, Boolean)) _
        As T

        Return FindOrCreate(table, find, Function(a))
    End Function

End Module
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using an extension method like so:

```
public static T FirstOrCreate<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) where T : class, new()
{
    var result = source.FirstOrDefault();
    return result != null ? result : new T();
}
```

If you want it to be able to accept a predicate, you can use this definition:

```
public static T FirstOrCreate<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) where T : class, new()
{
    var result = source.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
    return result != null ? result : new T();
}
```

That way you can use it in place of FirstOrDefault() like so:

```
Invoice selectedInvoice = (from i in Invoices
                           where i.ID == invoiceID
                           select i).FirstOrCreate();
```

..or with the use of a Predicate:

```
Invoice selectedInvoice = db.Invoices.FirstOrCreate(i => i.ID == invoiceID);
```

Will either return a matching entity or a new (non-null) entity instead.

Edit: I've been thinking about this today, and I occurs to me that the above will require you to detect that the entity is new (not existing) and attach it to the DataContext, so I came up with this compromise, using the same approach:

```
public static T FirstOrCreate<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, DataClassesDataContext db) where T : class, new()
{
    var result = source.FirstOrDefault();
    if (result == null)
    {
        result = new T();
        db.GetTable<T>().InsertOnSubmit(result);
    }
    return result;
}
```

The drawback is you have to pass the DataContext in as a parameter, but it should work nicely enough:

```
Customer selectedCustomer = (from c in db.Customers
                             where c.CustomerId == selectedCustomerId
                             select c).FirstOrCreate(db);
```

Surely one upvote is out there? :)

Answer (score 0):

It could be shortened to.

```
if(invoiceDb == null) ctx.Invoices.InsertOnSubmit(invoiceDB = new Invoice() {Number = invoiceNumber});
```

Comment: but then invoiceDb isn't assigned

Comment: Really? A downvote because I didn't give you a complete pasteable code example? It's intended to show you HOW to do it, not do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Null-Coalescing Operator (??)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)

```
var invoice = ctx.Invoices.SingleOrDefault(a => a.InvoicerId == InvoicerId &&
                                             a.Number == invoiceNumber) ??
                          new Invoice();
```

Comment: This will not add a new invoice to the table, however.

Comment: See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3F_Operator (I wrote the first version of that article, so I link it whenever I can)

Comment: Still needs the logic to determine if an insert is needed